# kendo Grid grouping incompatibility with row template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When I'm using other "groupable" row template doesn't work in the kendo grid
But before there was no problem and now how to use the grouping together of row template

I put the code I wrote in a review do

**jsfiddle :**

[Click here to check with jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/Dyb9Y/7/embedded/result/)

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '/api/clientssnapshot',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'get'
                }
            }
        });

        $('.table').kendoGrid({
            dataSource: ds,
            sortable: true,
            groupable: true,
            selectable: true,
            navigatable: true,
            height: 500,
            scrollable: true,
            rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#client-row-template").html().replace('class="k-alt"', '')),
            altRowTemplate: kendo.template($("#client-row-template").html()),//@class="k-alt"@
            dataBound: function () {
                $('.spark').sparkline([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 85, 2, 1]);
                //$('.spark').each(function (i, e) {
                //    var $this = $(this);
                //    //console.info($this.attr('data-inrate'));
                //    var arr = eval('[' + $this.attr('data-inrate') + ']');
                //    console.log(this);

                //    $this.sparkline(arr);
                //});

            }

        });

    });
</script>
<body class="menu_hover">

<script id="client-row-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">

  <tr role="row" class="k-alt">

             <td role="gridcell" >#=   Mac #</td>
             <td role="gridcell" >#=   RadioName #</td>

             <td role="gridcell" >  <a href="http://#= ApIp #" target="_blank">#=ApName#</a>   </td>
             <td role="gridcell" >  <a href="http://#= RemoteIp #" target="_blank">#=RemoteIp#</a>   </td>

             <td role="gridcell" > <a href=#"#= AccountingId #" target="_blank" > #= AccountingName # </a> </td>
             <td role="gridcell" >#=  TX #</td>
             <td role="gridcell" >#=  RX #</td>
              <td role="gridcell" >#= Signal #</td>
              <td role="gridcell" >#= Uptime #</td>
              <td role="gridcell">
                     <span class="spark" data-inrate="#= InRateHistory #"  >   </span>
                 </td>
    </tr>
</script>

            <div class="span6 box gradient main_stting">
                <div class="dataTables_filter" id="txtSearch">
                    <label>
                        Search:
                        <input type="text" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0"></label>
                </div>

                <div class="title">
                    <h3></h3>
                </div>
                <div class="content">

                    <table class="table">
                        <colgroup>
                            <!-- Mac           -->
                            <col style="width: 170px">
                            <col style="width: 150px">
                            <col style="width: 80px">
                            <col style="width: 160px">
                            <col style="width: 130px">
                            <col style="width: 44px">
                            <col style="width: 50px">
                            <col style="width: 50px">
                            <col style="width: 78px">
                            <!-- Usage         -->
                            <!--                 <col style="width: 100px" />-->
                        </colgroup>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Mac</th>
                                <th>Radio</th>
                                <th>AP</th>
                                <th>Remote IP</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>TX</th>
                                <th>RX</th>
                                <th>Signal</th>
                                <th>Uptime</th>
                                <th>Usage</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>


</body></html>
```

Comment: This time it is not that easy. When you group (for each new group) your template should add one extra cell. Can you use templates for each cell instead for the row and avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you group cells, KendoUI inserts a new cell in front of the existing but this is only done for the *standard* template, not for your templates.

My recommendation is switching to a template for each cell. Basically your column definition would become:

```
columns : [
    { field: "Mac", title: "Mac", width: 170 },
    { field: "RadioName", title: "Radio", width: 150 },
    { field: "ApName", title: "Ap", width: 80, template: '<a href="http://#= ApIp #" target="_blank">#=ApName#</a>' },
    { field: "RemoteIp", title: "Remote IP", width: 160, template: '<a href="http://#= RemoteIp #" target="_blank">#=RemoteIp#</a>' },
    { field: "AccountingName", title: "Name", width: 130, template: '<a href="#= AccountingId #" target="_blank"> #= AccountingName # </a>' },
    { field: "TX", title: "TX", width: 44  },
    { field: "RX", title: "RX", width: 50 },
    { field: "Signal", title: "Signal", width: 50 },
    { field: "Uptime", title: "Uptime", width: 78},
    { field: "Usage", title: "Usage", template: '<span class="spark" data-inrate="#= InRateHistory #">   </span>'  },
    { command: [ "edit" ], title: "&nbsp;" }
],
```

In addition, you simply define the grid HTML placeholder as:

```
<div class="table"></div>
```

Your JSFiddle modified here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Dyb9Y/10/

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in your own template with a trick that was posted in this thread: http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-grouping-problem-when-using-row-template-bug

Which contains this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/THRQV/

Here's the code from that fiddle.

Markup

```
<table id="grid" style="width: 100%;">
</table>

<script id="rowTemplate" type="text">             
     <tr>         
         #= new Array(this.group().length + 1).join('<td class="k-group-cell"></td>') #
         <td>${Id}</td>
         <td>${StatusText}</td>
         <td>${CommissionTypeText}</td>
     </tr>
</script>
```

Javascript

```
var localData = [
    {Id: 1, StatusText: "Status 1", CommissionTypeText: "Commission 1"},
    {Id: 2, StatusText: "Status 2", CommissionTypeText: "Commission 2"},
    {Id: 3, StatusText: "Status 3", CommissionTypeText: "Commission 3"}
];

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource( {
     data: localData,
     schema: {
         model: {
             fields: {
                 Id: { type: "number" },
                 StatusText: { type: "string" },
                 CommissionTypeText: { type: "string" }
             }
         }
     }
});

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
     dataSource: dataSource,
     rowTemplate: $.proxy(kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html()), dataSource),
     scrollable: true,
     height: 500,
     sortable: true,
     filterable: true,
     groupable: true,
     pageable: true,
     columns: [
         {
             field: "Id",
             title: "Id",
             filterable: false
         },
         {
             field: "StatusText",
             title: "StatusText"
         },
         {
             field: "CommissionTypeText",
             title: "CommissionTypeText"
         }
     ]
});
```

Basically you are passing in the datasource, calling group() on it, and injecting the group cell when applicable.