# How do you get kendo ui grouping, with angular, working properly with row templates?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When you group with Kendo UI Grid and you're using a row template, you lose a column and they get misaligned from the header row. I've found a couple of solutions but they are all based on using jquery and not AngularJs.

Similar Question, but it's using jQuery vs Angular. [kendo Grid grouping incompatibility with row template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589017/kendo-grid-grouping-incompatibility-with-row-template)

I have the same bug as here as well: http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/grid/grid-grouping-problem-when-using-row-template-bug.aspx#1948937

The difference is I'm not using jQuery, I'm using Angular.

I have a kendo ui grid defined in html like this:

**HTML**

```
<div kendo-grid="vm.myTaskListGrid" k-options="vm.gridOptions"></div>

<script id="tmpl-myTask-list-row" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="\\#/details/#:id#">#:projectName#</a></td>
        <td>#:name#</td>
        <td>#:statusName#</td>
        <td>#:parentTaskName#</td>
        <td>
            #:plannedCompletedDate#
            #:estimatedCompletedDate#
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue btn-sm" data-ng-click="vm.edit(#:id#)"><i class="fa fa-edit" /></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

my controller is setup like this..

**Angular Controller:**

```
vm.gridOptions = {
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: getMyTaskList
                },
                group: { field: "projectName" },
                pageSize: 25,
                sort: {
                    field: 'firstname',
                    dir: 'asc'
                }
            },
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            groupable: true,
            rowTemplate: kendo.template($('#tmpl-myTask-list-row').html()),
            columns: [
            {
                title: 'Project Name',
                field: 'projectName',
            },
            {
                title: 'Name',
                field: 'name'
            },
            {
                title: 'Status',
                field: 'statusName'
            },
            {
                title: 'Dependent Task',
                field: 'parentTaskName'
            },
            {
                title: 'Dates'
            },
            {
                title: ''
            }]
        };

        function getMyTaskList(options) {
            myTaskService.getMyTaskList(2, vm.showDone).then(function (response) {
                options.success(response);
            });
        };
```

Angular Service:

Adding this by request, and note the grid works fine when I don't try and fix this issue with the #-- row template and the $.proxy lines.

```
function getMyTaskList(userId, showDone) {
            return $http.get("/api/tasks/getMyTaskList?userId=" + userId + "&showDone=" + showDone);
        }
```

I've tried adding the suggested

on the gird I added:

```
        #= new Array(this.group().length + 1).join('<td class="k-group-cell"></td>') #
```

but I'm reading you have to add the $.proxy

```
$.proxy(kendo.template($('#tmpl-myTask-list-row').html()), getMyTaskList),
```

but the $.proxy on the controller doesn't seem work. If I had the #= new Array... code to the row template and don't include the $.proxy I get the error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

How do you get kendo ui grouping with angular working properly with row templates?

Comment: "$.proxy on the controller doesn't seem work": following the kendo forum link, you'd have to bind the dataSource, not the controller itself (or a function, like you're doing);

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what that pertains to replacing the $.proxy line.  the "getMyTaskList" returns the datasource that the grid is using and works. If I put "datasource" it's undefined of course,

Comment: I don't see how that function is returning a data source; it only represents the read handler; 1) create the datasource first, via new kendo.data.DataSource, 2) set it as prop on the gridOptions and 3) bind it to the template instead of getMyTaskList

Comment: Ok I added the service call. At the bottom of my first code example is the getMyTaskList function which brings back the data to the KendoGrid. This works fine. so are you saying my options.datsource:{transport: { read:shouldbeTemplate? }} not sure what I'd reference, put in the $.proxy line there?

Comment: nope, I'll try adding an answer (untested)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said, you need to

1. create the datasource first, via new kendo.data.DataSource,
2. set it as prop on the gridOptions and
3. bind it to the template instead of getMyTaskList

JS:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: getMyTaskList
    },
    group: {
        field: "projectName"
    },
    pageSize: 25,
    sort: {
        field: 'firstname',
        dir: 'asc'
    }
});
var t = $.proxy(kendo.template($('#tmpl-myTask-list-row').html()), dataSource);   

vm.gridOptions = {
    dataSource: dataSource,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    groupable: true,
    rowTemplate: t,
    columns: [{
        title: 'Project Name',
        field: 'projectName',
    }, {
        title: 'Name',
        field: 'name'
    }, {
        title: 'Status',
        field: 'statusName'
    }]
};
```